# Automatic model selection

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, regression

I am writing a machine learning master algorithm from scratch where the user just inputs the training and testing data, i was wondering is there a way to automatically decide what algorithm is to be used : regression vs classification

like for example, 
(assuming the last column is always the output and it is always a  number )

if we could search through the last column and decide what model it is by seeing if they are discrete class labels or continuous values.
How would one go about this?

and if not this method, is there a better one?

It is to be in python3.

Thank you.

Comment: scikit-learn has utilities code to detect [`type_of_target()`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target.html)

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thanks!! @VivekKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[type of target using sk-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target.html)

we can use the typeoftarget() function to get the type of targget : continuous, or label and hence can figure what type of problem it is, based on that.

This answer provided by @Vivekkumar works as i needed it to. 
Thank you!

May not always work. still needs to be better as we can fool it. but for the best case we can run an ML algorithm for this and use this as a model to train it better.

Answer (score 0):

The following bit of code should help determine if the value in the last column can be converted to a floating point number:

```
s_1 = 'text'
s_2 = '1.23'

for s in [s_1, s_2]:
    try:
        f = float(s)
        print(s, 'conversion to float was OK, value:', f)
    except:
        print(s, 'could not be converted to a number')
```

Comment: thanks for that! this can only be helpful though if the last column had the label names as alphabets, if the class labels are numbers themselves, how would i go about deciding if its a classification or regression problem?

Comment: If you are certain of some difference in the two, for example do all numbers have a decimal point and all classifiers do not?

Comment: i m trying to automate it, and hence i don't really have any information, i know i can just ask the user, but i would like to remove that overhead of asking the user, i want the user to just input the training and testing data sets. The problem is, i am not certain of any difference, like even class names can have decimal points if the user wishes it to be so.

Comment: If the text cannot convert to a number it should be a label. If the difference in this column is always "converts to a number or not" then that can be used to distinguish classifiers from data to be fitted. As an example, the text "Rohan.Baisantry" has a decimal point but will not convert to a number.

Comment: my problem only arises only if the class labels are numbers, but anyways, i think im just going to ask the user what type of problem it is and add a module to check what algorithm it is, maybe run an ml algorithm to figure out what problem it is!